# Laptop randomly crashing and turning off

Tags: arch-linux, crash, battery

For the last few days, and I don't remember what changed, my laptop has been randomly turning off once a day.

`last -x | head | tac` returns

```
reboot   system boot  5.13.4-arch2-1   Mon Jul 26 08:30 - 09:43  (01:12)
kon5oul  tty7         :0               Mon Jul 26 08:30 - 09:43  (01:12)
shutdown system down  5.13.4-arch2-1   Mon Jul 26 09:43 - 09:43  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  5.13.4-arch2-1   Mon Jul 26 09:43   still running
kon5oul  tty7         :0               Mon Jul 26 09:43 - crash  (05:00)
reboot   system boot  5.13.4-arch2-1   Mon Jul 26 14:44   still running
kon5oul  tty7         :0               Mon Jul 26 14:44 - crash  (01:59)
reboot   system boot  5.13.4-arch2-1   Mon Jul 26 16:43   still running
kon5oul  tty7         :0               Mon Jul 26 16:43   still logged in
```

And as soon as this happens, I check if the backside is overheated. I find it quite normal. Is it a battery issue? How should I go about it? I use Archlinux.

Comment: Does it turn off or does it reboot?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Turn off. No shutdown. Just powers off, even though connected to AC power

Comment: To (try to) rule out a hardware problem, you could leave it on for a few hours, maybe overnight at the BIOS setup screen.  If it turns off, then it is a hardware problem. If it doesn't, it could be still a hardware issue (the BIOS setup doesn't exactly stress the computer). You could try leaving it on with another operating system. From a Unix perspective, check the system logs, everything between two boots. Some problems might trigger a warning (for example "undervoltage" that only much later cause the shutdown).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani What logs should I check?

Comment: `/var/log/kern.log` might be a good starting point.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani /var/log/kern.log doesn't exist. Also, I left my laptop open overnight at the BIOS settings screen. In the morning it was off because the battery drained.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I noticed that almost every time this happens, I have been analyzing chess games using a browser based engine, which is a heavy task, before the crash. However, I ran `mprime` for 30 minutes and it ran a "torture test". So basically my CPU usage was 100% for 30 minutes straight. But my computer didn't crash. I don't understand at all

Comment: Your BIOS test was on battery, but does the normal crash occur on battery or also connected to AC?

Comment: @golimar Also on AC

Comment: Use some monitoring tool to check temperatures, CPU usage, disk usage, etc

Comment: Try leaving it on overnight in BIOS(UEFI) with AC connected and see if it turns off or not?

Comment: Try booting and using a live OS off of a thumb drive for a while to see if that crashes in a similar manner or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no idea about the source of the issue, I suggest you to collect any data from sensors available in a log.

There are many tools for this job such as [collectd](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/collectd/).

This step will give you/us a wide view of your system.